# Error (10454): VHDL syntax error at Lab09_1.vhd(55): right bound of range must be a constant

Tags: vhdl

I have a VHDL school project which is making a pipelining that only contain if, id, ex, and wb. My idea is to input and make a loop for each inputted instruction in range index. But I keep getting this error:

```
Error (10454): VHDL syntax error at Lab09_1.vhd(55): right bound of range must be a constant
```

The error is i need to use constant at the for loop, but i need to change the range value.
Here is my code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
entity Lab09_1 is
    port( clock,reset : in std_logic;
        data : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        opcode : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        rs,rt : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        hex0,hex1,hex2,hex3,hex4,hex5: out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
        hazard,ifetch,idecode,exec,wback : out std_logic);
end Lab09_1;
architecture code of Lab09_1 is
    --stage r0 r1 r2 r3
    constant r0: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0):="00"; --r0
    constant r1: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0):="10"; --r1
    constant r2: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0):="01"; --r2
    constant r3: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0):="11"; --r3
    signal r0x,r1x,r2x,r3x:std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    --stage t0 t1 t2 t3
    constant t0: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0):="001"; --1
    constant t1: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0):="010"; --2
    constant t2: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0):="011"; --3
    constant t3: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0):="100"; --4
    --array and class
    type instruction is record
        stage:std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
                datax:std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        opcodex:std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        rsx,rtx:std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        crs,crt:std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        end record;
    type array_inst is array (natural range <>) of instruction;
    signal inst:array_inst(0 downto 10);
    --index for array
    signal index:integer;
begin
    process(clock, reset)
        begin
        if(reset='1')then
            for i in inst'range loop
                inst(i).stage <= (others => '0');
                inst(i).datax <= (others => '0');
                inst(i).opcodex <= (others => '0');
                inst(i).rsx <= (others => '0');
                inst(i).rtx <= (others => '0');
                        end loop;
        elsif(clock'event and clock='1')then
            --instruction fetch
            inst(index).stage <= t0;
            inst(index).datax <= data;
            inst(index).opcodex <= opcode;
            inst(index).rsx <= rs;
            inst(index).rtx <= rt;
            --check every inputted instruction
            for i in 0 to index loop
                --instruction decode
                if inst(i).stage=t0 then
                    inst(i).stage <= t1;
                    case rs is
                        when r0 => inst(i).crs <= r0x;
                        when r1 => inst(i).crs <= r1x;
                        when r2 => inst(i).crs <= r2x;
                        when r3 => inst(i).crs <= r3x;
                    end case;
                    case rt is
                        when r0 => inst(i).crt <= r0x;
                        when r1 => inst(i).crt <= r1x;
                        when r2 => inst(i).crt <= r2x;
                        when r3 => inst(i).crt <= r3x;
                    end case;
                --execution
                elsif inst(i).stage=t1 then
                    inst(i).stage <= t2;
                end if;
            end loop;
        end if;
    end process;
    index <= index + 1;
end code;
```

here is my for loop that getting error:

```
for i in 0 to index loop
    --instruction decode
    if inst(i).stage=t0 then
        inst(i).stage <= t1;
        case rs is
                when r0 => inst(i).crs <= r0x;
            when r1 => inst(i).crs <= r1x;
            when r2 => inst(i).crs <= r2x;
            when r3 => inst(i).crs <= r3x;
        end case;
        case rt is
            when r0 => inst(i).crt <= r0x;
            when r1 => inst(i).crt <= r1x;
            when r2 => inst(i).crt <= r2x;
            when r3 => inst(i).crt <= r3x;
        end case;
    --execution
    elsif inst(i).stage=t1 then
        inst(i).stage <= t2;
    end if;
end loop;
```

anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: You dont specify what tool caused this error. The syntax error thrown is not a VHDL syntax error, I suspect it is a synthesis tool limitation that requires loops to have static ranges (which is common with synth tools). You also have a problem, that `index` is incremented outside of a clocked process. Hence this is going to create a combinatorial loop and not going to work on real hardware.

Comment: sorry to reply now since i got so many homework. owh yeah, my index is incremented outside of a clocked process, and i'm just realized the error. Thank youuu.

Answer (score 0):

Like the error says, the loop range has to be constant.

You could replace the

```
for i in 0 to index loop
```

with a constant range and executing the loop conditionally depending on the value of `index` signal. So something like:

```
for i in inst'range loop
   if i <= index then
      -- Loop body....
```

Also note that the index signal might have to be incremented somewhere else than outside the process :). And if your original code had worked, then there might have been risk of violating the bounds of `inst`.

Comment: Yoooo, it's really help fullll. Thank you so muchh...